# How to export an Access database and import to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, export

I am working on a Java project that sources data from an MS Access database, but I want to use MySQL because I have found it to be very easy to manage. How can I export an Access database that has tables of 8 MB and more, and move the data to MySQL?

Comment: To expand on @Dekel's answer, there's a video of the process [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9LxGF3Qc90).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ODBC to connect from MSAccess to MySQL.
[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-export.html) is an example.

What you should actually do is:

1. Configure a new ODBC DNS connection ([this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows.html) might help)
2. Inside access - click on the table you would like to export, click on the `file` menu, then go to `export` and choose the name for the export
3. Select the ODBC connection you just created from the list of files of type.

MSAccess will connect to your MySQL server and export the data in that table to your MySQL database.

Comment: Just a head's up about DBA.SE. Link only answers are normally frowned upon (link rot). Maybe you could expand on this answer - provide the steps? Also, please use the formatting tools provided - in this case the link tool allowing one to embed the link in a relevant word (Edited).

Comment: @Vérace, thanks for that. As for the steps - they are very easy to produce based on the link, so I thought it will not make sense to just copy what's written there.

Comment: Well, just a summary should do - it's just as I said though, link rot does occur.

Comment: Ok, made some changes. I think now it's better :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is:

1. Export Access data to xml
2. Go to phpmyadmin Import that xml file.

**Note: if the xml file size is bigger than max upload size import through command line / bash or Terminal**

Comment: Can i have this xml file in general format for learning purpose.?